# Custom Save on List Instance

Tags: list, custom-list, 2016, custom-form, form

I have already configured a way on how to call a code behind method on click of Save button. I want to get the field values from the form. What is the way to do it?

[image]

Code Behind:

[image]

Comment: Are you using event listener? If Yes, which event listener you are using? Or do you want to fetch this values using javascript?

Comment: No I'm not using event listener. I want to fetch form field values on code behind

Comment: Have you tried using PreSaveAction??